# Return a value if it does not exist in a document

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using Pandas to read from an excel document and create data frames from the products. So far I have gotten it to pick up and print products that exist in the table, but not things that don't. I need all the products to be listed, just with 0's in all other fields. I have tried this to find values that DO exist and it works fine:

```
def types(row):
    if row['Produce'] in ('Apple','Orange','Mango'):
        return 'Fruit'
    if row['Produce'] in ('Potato','Carrot','Lettuce'):
        return 'Vegetable'
    return 'Misc'
```

However, if I do something like this, it doesn't pull anything:

```
def fruit(row):

        if row['Produce'] in ('Apple'):
            return 'Apple'
        return 'Apple'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`('Apple')` is not a tuple. It's a string with redundant parenthesis. try `('Apple',)`. (Note the comma at the end. One-item tuples need to be written this way.